# RegEx exclude sets while grouping all characters 2 by 2

Tags: regex, regex-group, mutual-exclusion

I want to modify a binary file with a pattern. I've converted the file to a plain hexdump with `xxd` (from package vim). The plain file looks like this (only 1 line with no trailing LF):

```
$ xxd -ps file.bin | tr -d '\n' | tee out.txt
3a0a5354...
```

I want to remove all patterns that match `\x01[^\xFF]*\xFF` (an opening token and a closing token and everything between them except another closing token) in the **original file**, but **`sed`** doesn't work like this.

Example Input and Desired Match:

```
020202020101010101feeffeefff0000...
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And I'm thinking about doing this:

```
sed 's/regex//g' in.file > out.file
```

Now I'm trying to match all chatacters **2-by-2 while excluding `ff`**. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some example inputs and outputs? `xxd` (like `hd`) output has positioning metadata in its output.  `sed` isn't going to be terribly good at that. How about perl? `perl -pe 's/\x01[^\xff]*\xff'//`

Comment: @AdamKatz I used option `-ps` for xxd

Comment: Great.  We still need example input and output to know what you're trying to do.  You seem to be asking for patterns that match regex [`\x01[^\xFF]*\xFF`](https://regex101.com/r/Ts0QpE/1) related to character codes, but then you describe a completely different regex related to hex pairs, which might be satisfied with [`(?:..)*?(?!ff)(..)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ts0QpE/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`((..)|01([0-9a-e][0-9a-f]|[0-9a-f][0-9a-e])*ff)*`

That is, we match pairs of hexadecimal digits where either the first or the second digit can be f but not both. In the surrounding context we must also match everything two characters at a time to ensure that our matches start from an even digit.

Obviously, you must add something that actually removes the inner group from the output, which is specific to your regex engine. I realized only after posting this that a simple s/ won't do.